# How do I query a text range in Power BI using the URL to filter?

Tags: url, powerbi, query-string, power-bi-report-server

I have a Winform app that has an embedded PowerBI report. I'm using the winforms controls to determine how the data gets filtered. The values from the controls are appended to the Power BI URL using `?filter` and it's working pretty well. However, it doesn't cover all types of filtering.

For instance, I have a table that has values such as '00001', '00023', 00145', '00213', '05345', 08966', etc. I try to append to the filter like so, `urlString = urlString + " and TableA/ColumnC ge '00000'" + " and TableA/ColumnC le '00300'";` It should return the table with columns that have '00023', '00145', and '00213'. Instead it doesn't filter at all. Like nothing happened.

The DAX query below does the type of filtering that I want. But it has to be dynamic.

```
EVALUATE
    CALCULATETABLE (
        TableA,
        TableA[ColumnC] >= "00000" && TableA[ColumnC] <= "00300"
    )
```

I saw that you can have a something like `https://powerbirs/reports/powerbi/FolderA/NewReport?rs:embed=true&query={dax query here}`

I don't know how to put the DAX query in the URL. How do I do that?

I'm open to other alternatives as well.